# jQuery Walidate and textareas

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, textarea

I have a little problem over here with the jQuery "Walidate" plugin ( http://jquery.dop-trois.org/walidate/ ) in connection with texareas.

```
$("textarea").walidate("validate");
```

This just doesn't seem to work. I mean, the textarea gets marked as required correctly if nothing is written inside, but thats also the case when there is something written inside! It's still marked as required when it shouldn't :(

Is it possible that Walidate doesn't work for textareas? Is there a work-around? It's not that hard to check by myself via javascript but it would be nice if Walidate could do that for me.

Thanks for reading and maybe commenting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now fixed in the newer Version 2.4.3.1
I've added `textarea` in `textElementSelector`.